# How do I extract data from a zip archive that is represented as byte []?

Tags: java

How do I extract data from a zip archive that is represented as byte []?

```
public static byte[] extractSingleFile(byte[] zip) {
        final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(zip);
        final ZipInputStream gzipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
        final byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(gzipInputStream);

        return bytes;
}
```

Always returns an empty byte []

If I write byte [] zip as a file to disk using

```
final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("somefile.zip"));
fileOutputStream.write(zip);
```

Then the created zip archive is opened normally (i.e. the problem is not in the array passed to the method)

Comment: How are u creating the `byte[] zip` ?

Comment: Byte [] zip is created in another third-party service. But if it is written as a file to disk, it is normally open

Comment: Are u sure the service returns gzip itself ? or is it some other kind of zipping ?

Comment: I tried using GZipInputStreat. Error occurs that this is not a GZIP stream

Comment: ` gis = GZIPInputStream(inputStream)
            `in` = InputStreamReader(gis)
            reader = BufferedReader(`in`)
            var line: String?
            while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                outPut.append(line).append("\n")
            }`
the code works fine for me in case of gzips, I think its mostly to do with the zip format of the file. Trying writing to file and then reading the file using your code.